# Plesk Schedule Task Empty File

Tags: scheduled-tasks, plesk, cron-task

I want to create a ***cron job*** from scheduled tasks in ***Plesk***. I am facing a weird problem with it, I have created the task and my command runs successfully if I press "Run now". If I let it runs automatically every 1 hour the file is empty.

Here is my command:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u username -p'pass' dbname > path/mybackup.sql
```